# Missing SonarQube for MS Build 4.0 build step in TFS build steps

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, azure-pipelines-build-task, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

Sonarqube was working fine until I'm trying to scan a new project with Xunit tests and got this error:

```
error MSB4062: The "IsTestFileByName" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\temp\ConsoleApp2017\.sonarqube\bin\SonarQube.Integration.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0
```

according to https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-310

it seems like we need to upgrade to SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild to v4.0 in tfs.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube#overview

Which is what we did and the upgrade went through, installed, but we're not seeing any new build steps for the new scanner, it's still showing up as 
Version: 3.0.0

We're using:

```
Java 8 on both SonarQube server and scanner
SonarQube Version 6.2
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 3.0
Sonar C# 6.1.0.2359
MSBuild 15.0
TFS Version 14.114.26403.0
```

Tried restarting the tfs server but no luck.

Comment: Hi, don't you see a small flag on your existing steps in your build definitions? Because we increase the major version of the tasks in the v4 of the extension, you have to opt-in to benefit from the new version of the task.

Answer (score 0):

Just try using **version 4** as Fabrice mentioned:

Besides, you can refer to [this link](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-msbuild/releases) to get the **SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 4.0.**

[image]